# Can I stop Bump from being activated when the phone bumps?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, bump

I like the idea behind bump, and I am using it in an application. However, I'd prefer it if I would be able to make a connection between 2 phones (in close proximity) without the users having to bump.

I have tried `simulateBump` which works pretty good for that purpose. However I don't want the Bump framework to be activated when it thinks the phones are bumped.

So, how could you disable 'bumping'?

Also, one extra questions: Can I stop the bump framework from triggering a vibration on the phone when the phone is bumped?

Comment: can you put in some code? otherwise the question gets very focused and not many can help...

Comment: @Srikar. Hmm..there's really no code I can add that I'm having trouble with. Everything is included in the bump framework. I just want to know how to disable a certain functionality from the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so others know what Andrei is talking about - [Bump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_%28application%29) allows two smartphone users to physically bump their phones together to transfer contact information, photos, and files to each other over the Internet.

Now that the context is clear, These are the exposed API's by Bump - [Bump API for iOS](https://github.com/bumptech/bump-api-ios/blob/master/libBump/BumpClient.h). According to this -

1. When phones are bumped and if you have included the Bump SDK in your app complete with delegates, Bump framework will be activated when 2 phones bump. If you dont want bump to be activated then remove bump handlers (like `configureWithAPIKey` etc.) and implement you own. Although I see a `BOOL` flag called `bumpable`. This is defaulted to `YES`. Maybe if you set this to `FALSE` and see how it works out.
2. I dont see any API to turn off vibration when bump happens.

I am purely basing this on my observations of their header file. Not tried this in xCode. So I might be wrong.

Also, if you are interested in peer-to-peer data transfer you might want to take a look at [GameKit](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/bluetooth-connectivity-with-gamekit/), its a cool piece of tech part of iOS framework..

Comment: Thanks @Srikar. Really simple in the end. The `bumpable` `BOOL` value needs to be set to `NO` and just use the `[[BumpClient sharedClient] simulateBump]` method.